# How to go about a remote shutdown program?

Tags: linux, protocol

i've been wrapping my head around this and I want some ideas.
How would I go about making a remote shutdown program for one computer to shutdown another?
Would I use http or another protocol?
I was thinking like a direct message from a computer to another and a listener program on the computer to get shutdown that would shutdown on a certain message.

Thanks! Be creative.

PS: *nix operating system

Comment: What kind of computer?  Linux?  Mac? Windows? Mainframe?

Comment: Linux, im currently looking into talk and write command but meh

Comment: Be sure to update your question with the clarification.

Comment: Alrighty, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open an [SSH](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssh1.html) connection from the command computer to the listener computer, log in with an authorized user and send [`shutdown -h now`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/shutdown8.html).

A simple one-line shell script should do.

Comment: Meh i was looking for an actual listener sender type of thing, thats the easy way around :/

Comment: @HiperBolt But that's exactly what this is. The SSH server is the listener and the SSH client is the sender. Why overcomplicate this when Linux provides you the tools you need out-of-the-box?

Comment: True true.. It will get harder to do this from my phone though... :p